# The script resource is behind a redirect, which is disallowed - Service Worker

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, service-worker

I'm using Service worker in my **Angular** application and everything works fine in my localhost. But when I try to push this code and deploy it in the development/diff environment, I get the following error

```
Service worker registration failed: SecurityError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://a.b.czoo.org/') with script ('https://a.b.czoo.org/sw.js'): 
The script resource is behind a redirect, which is disallowed.
```

**Note: Mentioned URL (https://a.b.czoo.org/) is the root domain format. (Just added, a, b, and czoo at respective places). My code is deployed on the custom branch and the final URL will be like 'https://a.b.czoo.org/AB-123' where AB-123 is my branch name.**

*(More context ...)*

I'm using typescript in my Service worker file. The file will be in a different location and during the build process, Webpack converts this file using `ts-loader` and `worker-loader` and puts this file in the app root folder which will be referenced in the `src/app.component.ts` file. Like this,

**app.component.ts**

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', { scope: '/' }).then(
  (): void => {
    console.log('Service worker registered');
  },
  (error): void => {
    console.error(`Service worker registration failed: ${error}`);
  },
);
```

This service worker file is imported via an `entry` option in the Webpack config. (that's how happening in local env)

**webpack.config.js**

```
entry: {
  vendor: config.vendor.packages,
  boot: './app/index.aot.ts',
  sw: './app/**/**/sw.ts',
},
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.sw\.ts$/,
      use: [
        {
          // this is expected to generate new sw.js file in the root which is referenced in app.component
          loader: 'worker-loader',
          options: {
            filename: "[name].js",
            publicPath: "/",
          },
        },
        {
          loader: 'ts-loader',
          options: {
            transpileOnly: true,
            happyPackMode: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ]
},
```

My build is successful but when I try to hit the development URL, (https://a.b.czoo.org/AB-123) I get the aforementioned error.

Checked the following issues ([SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43321477/the-script-resource-is-behind-a-redirect-which-is-disallowed), [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30684)) but was unable to get to the root cause/reason of the issue. First of all, I'm not sure how to debug this.

I need guidance on how to debug this issue or what could be the possible reason. Any answers will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: If you inspect the service worker request in the Network tab of the browser dev tools, does it show a response header for the location it's redirecting to?

Comment: Also, does using a relative route for the request via `navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')` make any difference?

Comment: The error says that your request to `sw.js` is being redirected. What's it being redirected to? Is it being redirected from `http` to `https`? Or from `mywebsite.com` to `www.mywebsite.com`? If you check the network tab of Chrome Dev Tools, it should have more information. (Anyways, it's likely happening because of your dev enviroment `apache/ngnix/IIS` settings causing a redirect, not necessarily because of your angular settings.)

Answer (score 2):

Try running

```
let w = await fetch("/sw.js", { redirect: "error" })
console.log(w)
```

and check where is it redirected

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to make a request to the url that returns the `302` in a `httpClient.get` call before you set up your worker and then use the updated `response.url` to point to the post redirect url for your script.

```
this.httpClient.get('https://path_to_script/script.js', {
    observe: 'response'
  })
  .pipe(
    tap((response) => {
      // response.url is the new redirected url;
      navigator.serviceWorker.register(response.url as string, {
        scope: '/'
      }).then(
        () => {
          console.log('Service worker registered');
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error(`Service worker registration failed: ${error}`);
        }
      );
    }),
    catchError((e: any) => {
      console.log(e);
      return e;
    })
  ).subscribe((r) => { console.log(r); // have to subscribe otherwise client wont make request. });
```